# ReactJs How to use values of a component in another component which is not its child?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code to call to use routes which is working fine now for all routes. I have some API values available in the Header component. How can i use those values in Route component?

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="loginPage">
      <Header />
      <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Depends on what data flow framework you are using. With Redux, you can connect the application state to specific containers. This means you would have to create a flow to store the information from one container into the application state, connect a different component, and pass along the data you want. https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

- Use a data flow framework like [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react). But [you might not need redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367).
- Store the data in the state of the parent component, and pass it along through props (along with a function to modify it, if needed):

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          data: {}
      }
  }

  setData = (data) => this.setState({ data })

  render() {
      let { data } = this.state

      return (
          <div className="loginPage">
            <Header data={data} setData={this.setData} />
            <Routes data={data} setData={this.setData} />
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

- Access the Header component through [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).  This is usually not recommended, but it can be helpful, especially when working with third-party components.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.header_ref = null
    }

    doSomethingWithHeaderRef = () => {
      if (this.header_ref == null)
        return

      let data = this.header_ref.data 

      //do stuff
    }


    render() {
        return (
          <div className="loginPage">
            <Header ref={ref => this.header_ref = ref} />
            <Routes 
              doSomething={doSomethingWithHeaderRef}
              header_ref={this.header_ref}
            />
          </div>
        );
    }
 }
```